# How do I filter multiple items from an array and add to an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ngrx

Take the following array:

```
[
    {
        ndc: '0093415580',
        name: 'Amoxicillin',
        prescribing_physician: 'John Doe',
        quantity: 150,
        day_supply: 10,
        pharmacy: 'Walmart',
        source: 'Auto',
    },
    {
        ndc: '499990882',
        name: 'Lipitor',
        prescribing_physician: 'John Doe',
        quantity: 10,
        day_supply: 30,
        pharmacy: 'CVS Health',
        source: 'Auto',
    },
    {
        ndc: '5528947530',
        name: 'Celebrix',
        prescribing_physician: 'John Doe',
        quantity: 25,
        day_supply: 30,
        pharmacy: 'CVS Health',
        source: 'Manual',
    },
];
```

How can I filter out all the `name` and `day_supply` and set them as key and values pairs into an array with objects like so?

```
myArr = [
    {
        name: 'Amoxicillin',
        value: '10'
    },
    {
        name: 'Lipitor',
        value: '30'
    },
    {
        name: 'Celebrix,
        value: '30'
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to process each object, returning only the `name` and `day_supply` (as `value`) values:

```js
const data = [{
    ndc: '0093415580',
    name: 'Amoxicillin',
    prescribing_physician: 'John Doe',
    quantity: 150,
    day_supply: 10,
    pharmacy: 'Walmart',
    source: 'Auto',
  },
  {
    ndc: '499990882',
    name: 'Lipitor',
    prescribing_physician: 'John Doe',
    quantity: 10,
    day_supply: 30,
    pharmacy: 'CVS Health',
    source: 'Auto',
  },
  {
    ndc: '5528947530',
    name: 'Celebrix',
    prescribing_physician: 'John Doe',
    quantity: 25,
    day_supply: 30,
    pharmacy: 'CVS Health',
    source: 'Manual',
  },
];

const myArr = data.map(({ name, day_supply }) => ({ name,  value: day_supply }));
console.log(myArr);

const myObj = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ name, day_supply }) => [name, day_supply]));
console.log(myObj);
```

Note that you may find an object with the `name` values as properties to be more useful, the above snippet shows how to produce that using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).